# Rails deployment application version specific update script

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3, mongoid4

I am deploying regular updates for my Rails application with Capistrano and I keep a version number as a string in a global constant.

I would like to be a able to deploy/run a simple script only once for a specific update, that will perform some operations on the database (I am using **mongoid**, and I have modified the schema a bit)

Let's say I am under version 0.1.25 and upgrading to 0.1.26, I'd like to run this custom script **only once** for servers that are 0.1.25 or below (the script won't be ran again for next updates like 0.1.26 to 0.1.27)

```
MyModel.all.each do |instance|
  instance.new_field_with_v26 = somefunction
end
```

I believe this can be implemented as a Capistrano task, but how do I retrieve the previous value of that constant ? (`Application::VERSION_NUMBER`)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this using a migrations system, which Capistrano can then run. For example: https://github.com/adacosta/mongoid_rails_migrations

At a bare minimum, something like this might serve as a template:

- Store the schema version in the database.
- When you make a change to the schema, increment the schema version in the code.
- Write a Rake task to run the pertinent migrations.

I hope this is helpful.